# Should I change app IDs before re-launching

Tags: android, ios

I have inherited an app on both iOS and Android which was already released. I'm looking to re-launch it as a new app instead of an "update" (few reason why but I'll skip for now).

- I've deleted the from iOS App Store.
- I've read that you can't delete an app from Google Play but instead 'unpublish it'.

**That's fine but my main question is:**

Do I have to (or should I) change the `iOS Bundle ID` and `Android Package Name` before releasing as a new app?

Thanks

Comment: `Android Package Name before releasing as a new app?` yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You should change the app IDs  because  app Ids are there for the identification of Application so it must be unique . Just try to install 2 application signed with different certificate and same app id.